# Optimizing Launch Image IPA size for ios7+

Tags: ios, xcode, png, filesize, ipa

I have an application with a visually complex LaunchImage. Even without the addition of iPhone6/6+ LaunchImages, there are already 10Mb (!!!) of PNGs in the final compressed IPA, as verified using unzip -v on the IPA. I would like to significantly reduce this.

The ideal situation would be the ability to supply a single 2630x1536 image that can be scaled and centre cut appropriately, but such a thing is "impossible" in the world of iOS HIG disciples. I'm also aware that under HiG, the launchimage is not a splash, but for this app (game) that's how the bootflow is designed on all platforms, so please limit answers to technical responses.

Things I have already discovered:

- XCode PNGCrush increases the size of our retina iPad launchImage from 3.3 to 5.5Mb. Disabling "optimize PNGs" in XCode and doing a custom PNG optimize on the source image helps.
- We are iOS7 only, so XCode's assetCatalogue help says that "images are optimized into a binary format to reduce app download time". I see no evidence of this. I just see the same PNGs in the assetCatalogue in a folder called "LaunchImage.launchimage". Does anyone know what this optimization is?
- To confirm, if the AssetCatalog is used, and only ios7+ is supported, I can nuke any "default*.png" LaunchImages in the project as these are simply duplicates for iOS6?
- AssetCatalogs appear to support 8-bit palletized launchimages, and 256-colours dithered on a retina display actually looks pretty good.

Are there any other optimization options available? Can I, for example, leave out the iPad@1x image and have the OS downscale the 2048x1536 image (what unimaginable horror, almost as awful as not providing 5 separate resolutions of App Store promo video!)

Additionally, this LaunchImage is also displayed on a second splash screen shown by the application (we launch the app with the launchimage plus some custom animation before streaming in all other data.) From the user's perspective, they see a single continuous splash screen, with animation starting over it during the 2nd part of the load.

I would like to re-use the "official" launchImage for display on this screen. Is there a reliable way of getting the LaunchImage filename that was displayed on this device that won't likely break with the release of new devices? Currently, I store and load my own, 2630x1536 image, and scale and centre-crop it (incidentally, you can't see the difference) to be safe, but if I could discard that image and safely get the launchimage filename used on this device that would be great.

Comment: ".. images are optimized .." may very well be the (in)famous PNG frying that you disabled through XCode. Its purpose is *not* "to reduce app download time" (because the PNG compression ought to be unchanged), but it *may* be slightly faster displayed because the RGB triplets are re-ordered in a way favourably to iOS.

Comment: Whether the core PNG compression is unchanged, the iPad@2x image demonstrably goes from 3.3Mb (my source) to 5.3Mb with "compress PNG images enabled", mirroring findings here. http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/. I'm not convinced that on gigahertz-class devices, the RGB order of the splash screen matters more than milliseconds, and there's no alpha to premultiply.

Comment: I would suggest that you examine your image data to see if the image could be converted to a PNG with 8bit table values. This means that it would only be making use of 256 colors, but this can end up saving quite a bit of space with very large PNG images. If you only provide a 2x version, the system should find it and use it for the 1x display, but you will have to double check to make sure hat works.